# Upgrading to Devise 3.2.2 - image upload gives error "no file chosen"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm upgrading my Rails app from 3.2 to 4, which I got working well, except for new user sign up with Devise. I'm upgrading to Devise 3.2.2. When I try to sign up a new user I get the error, "No File Chosen Can't Be Blank" for the user's image. I don't think it's an issue with Paperclip, because images uploaded with my other models work fine. I see that it says there are unpermitted parameters, which might be a sign of an issue. Here is the section of the User model:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "75x108>"}
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
    content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'] },  
    size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
```

Here is my sign up page:

```
<div class="panel panel-default form_page"> 
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
 </div>  
 <div class="panel-body input_container">
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :image, label: "Upload A Profile Pic" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :name, input_html: {:class => "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :email, input_html: {:class => "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :password, input_html: {:class => "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, input_html: {:class => "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :twitter, label: "Enter your Twitter handle", input_html: {:class => "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :lastfm, label: "Enter your last.fm handle", input_html: {:class => "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :status, label: "Leave some words of wisdom", input_html: {:class => "form-control" } %>   
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
</div>
 <div class="panel-footer">
   <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
 </div>
```

Here is my server output:

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"akj/sZRPil4h3tu9qntjmbgucai2h80/b8U3zhYtEoQ=", "user"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000106bd3dd0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/r8/z7hzv9r51nv9vymbj1szxqdw0000gp/T/RackMultipart20140129-36058-dwch5z>, @original_filename="tony.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[image]\"; filename=\"tony.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "name"=>"Tony", "email"=>"user6@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "twitter"=>"@Tambe257", "lastfm"=>"Tambe257", "status"=>"words"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: image, name, twitter, lastfm, status
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'user6@example.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Comment: Your hunch about strong parameters is correct.  Read this for more information on strong parameters and Devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: @Dhaulagiri Thanks! I added all of u.permit parameters to the controller. If you want to leave it as an answer I'll check it off as solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hunch about strong parameters is correct. Read [this](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) for more information on strong parameters and Devise and it should help you solve your issue.  Something like this, where :username is the field you want to add.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```